# LATEX: delete the number of page from the backmatter

Tags: latex

im tring to delete the page number from my \backmatter sequence. I've succeded to do this, writing this code:

```
\begin{document}
.
.
.
    \backmatter
    \begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \let\ps@plain\ps@empty
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Allegati}
    \input{Allegati}
    \input{Bibliografia}
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \listof{grafico}{Elenco dei grafici}

    \endgroup




    \end{document}
```

But, I don't know why, the last page of my document still have his number. In the code above the last page is a graphic list, but if I change the order of my sequence, for example putting the bibliography in the last position, the this element will present the page number. I'm writing this document using the book class.

Someone can help me?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you did not provide a MWE (Minimal Working Example) I can just guess what your document's preamble contains.

Have a look at this code please:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \lhead{}
    \chead{}
    \rhead{}
    \lfoot{}
    \cfoot{}
    \rfoot{}
}

\begin{document}
    text
    \newpage
    text
    \newpage
    \backmatter
    \begingroup
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Allegati}
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    %\listof{grafico}{Elenco dei grafici}
    \endgroup
\end{document}
```

EDIT1: 
This way you redefine the `plain`-style that is used by **every** chapter-page in your document.

If you do not want to change it document-wide, your approach is correct; just add a `\clearpage` before the last `\endgroup`. It won't create a new page, but delete the pagenumber. Btw, if you don't *really* need the `\begingroup` `\endgroup` leave it out, this will also delete the last page number.

END-EDIT1

A few things to note:

1. If you use plain book-class, you can use `fancyhdr` for setting a
   page style like in the above example. Later just load the wanted
   pagestyle and from there on it will be used.
2. If you want to write a document according to the modern
   standard of LaTeX, maybe think about using a KOMA-class, which
   provides great functions for changing the page style (and often they
   also work better ;))

For me this MWE does work, having no pagenumber on the last page; if it does not for you, please give us more information about your document.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I try your suggestion, and if i have understood, it redefined the style plain. Could be a good solution for my future documents, but right now i need to keep the classic plain style.  I thought that my code was a goodexample. What do you need? The preamble?

Comment: Yes, I would have needed a code that I'm able to run on my own machine, to reproduce the error. But it should work now too ;) Just have a look at the EDIT1 in my answer. You only need to add the `\clearpage` before the last `\endgroup`.

Comment: It works perfectly just adding the \clearpage as you suggested.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to hear that! Maybe mark my above asnwer as Solution, so others can find it easier.